# Correct way to switch back to iptables on debian 10 or 11

Tags: debian, iptables, configuration, nftables

With debian 10 and 11 nftables is the new firewalling framework.

I have some machines that rely heavily on a old custom iptables config, aside from that I can easily move everything to new debian 10/11 installations or upgrading the previous ones, no problem with most of other services being updated to current versions.

Now, while I get myself a certain amount of time to learn nftables (because I want to learn it decently and tweak it finely to my needs*):

**What could be a right way to disable nftables and use iptables + iptables-persistent for now ?**

(I would like to take advantage of all the security updates and fixes debian 10 carries with it while getting my time to slowly move to nftables.)

ALSO BONUS

*I would like to do the opposite once I finished my nftables configuration so: how to switch back to nftables and disable iptables ?*

In some sorts I'm asking basically **how to switch back and forth between iptables and nftables on debian 10 and 11 ?**

*I know that there's an utility to help move from iptables to nftables syntax but I prefer  don't rely on automatic conversion. So for now I prefere put iptables back in place and slowly change the rules manually.

Answer (score 6):

It is documented on [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/iptables):

```
update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ip6tables /usr/sbin/ip6tables-legacy
update-alternatives --set arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy
update-alternatives --set ebtables /usr/sbin/ebtables-legacy
```

Comment: doesn't work on Debian 11, after installing iptables only the first 2 rows work.

Comment: @Dani `arptables` and `ebtables` don't come with `iptables`, but as separate packages: if you have only the `iptables` package installed, the last two commands can and should be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

I switched back to iptables on Debian 11 doing the following:

Installation of *ebtables*, *arptables*

Changed `update-alternatives` for ebtables and arptables as follows. one example for arptables below. ebtables works the same, as long as the packages are installed. Luckily the binary files for both versions contain either "legacy" or "nft"

```
    update-alternatives --install /usr/sbin/arptables arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy 10 --slave /usr/sbin/arptables-save arptables-save /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy-save --slave /usr/sbin/arptables-restore arptables-restore /usr/sbin/arptables-legacy-restore
    update-alternatives --install /usr/sbin/arptables arptables /usr/sbin/arptables-nft 20 --slave /usr/sbin/arptables-save arptables-save /usr/sbin/arptables-nft-save --slave /usr/sbin/arptables-restore arptables-restore /usr/sbin/arptables-nft-restore
```

if you made a typo (like me) which leads to error messages about wrong symlinks you could remove the update-alternative configs by hand using:

```
rm /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/arptables`
```

but I suggest to use the `update-alternatives` command for every action.

You should check update-alternative for all commands (iptables, ip6tables, ebtables, arptables) afterwards with .. `--display`

Change backend in `/etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf`:

```
    #FirewallBackend=nftables
    FirewallBackend=iptables
```

Maybe issue an `systemctl restart firewalld.service` and do a reboot to be sure it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can still use iptables in Debian 10 and 11. The default configuration
on new 11 (aka bullseye) deployments does not install iptables but it can be added easily.

By default iptables utilities (iptables, iptables-save, ebtables etc.) will actually configure the nftables filter (and create nftables rules). So iptables is actually a link to iptables-nft.

The packages netfilter-persistent and iptables are still available, providing both iptables-nft and iptables-legacy, see:

```
# apt info iptables
```

If you use iptables-nft you can just load iptables rules and list them with.

```
# nft list ruleset
```

Pay attention - if you modify the configuration using nftables changes will not be readable by iptables, so you can't really move back and forth.

You are taking the right approach by not relying on automatic conversion and taking the time to study the new network filter. After you get used to the new syntax you can create configurations that are easier to manage and operate.